# How can I map items together in a json structure with jq?

Tags: json, path, jq

I have a json structure that looks like this:

```
{
        "lorry1": {
                "box1": [
                        {"item": "shoes", "state": "new"},
                        {"item": "snacks", "state": "new"}
                ],
                "box2": [
                        {"item": "beer", "state": "cold"},
                        {"item": "potatoes"}
                ]
        },
        "lorry2": {
                "box1": [
                        {"item": "shoes", "state": "new"},
                        {"item": "snacks", "state": "new"}
                ],
                "box2": [
                        {"item": "beer", "state": "lukewarm"}
                ]
        }
}
```

Now I want to know where I can find shoes:
I could come up with this jq query:

```
to_entries | select(.[].value | .[][].item=="shoes") | map({"lorry": "\(.key)"  })
```

But that only gives me the lorries. Useful, but not quite there yet. I'd like to know the box they're in as well.

I came up with this, but it obviously is not correct:

```
to_entries | select(.[].value | .[][].item=="shoes") | keys as $box |map({"lorry": "\(.key)", "box": $box })
```

The answer I'd like to get is lorry1, box1 and lorry2, box1.

Even better yet: I'd like to find all items and provide the information, like this:

```
"shoes": [ {"lorry1", "box1"}, {"lorry2", "box1" } ],
"snacks": [ {"lorry1", "box1"}, {"lorry2", "box1"} ],
"beer": [ {"lorry1", "box2"}, {"lorry2", "box2"} ],
"potatoes": [ {"lorry1", "box2"} ]
```

but that may be asking a bit too much :)

Comment: are you sure you want your final output in a non-JSON format? asking because `{"lorry1", "box1"},` - is not a valid JSON

Comment: I should've written that better, indeed. the thought just popped up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a overkill to me but it does the job.

```
[path(.[][][].item) as $p | [$p, getpath($p)]] |
group_by( .[1] ) |
map({(.[0][1]): (. | map([.[0][0,1]]))})|
add
```

Save the above `jq` filter in file `item_in.jq` and run it as `jq --from-file item_in.jq`. Passing your input to this gives the following output:

```
{
  "beer": [
    [
      "lorry1",
      "box2"
    ],
    [
      "lorry2",
      "box2"
    ]
  ],
  "potatoes": [
    [
      "lorry1",
      "box2"
    ]
  ],
  "shoes": [
    [
      "lorry1",
      "box1"
    ],
    [
      "lorry2",
      "box1"
    ]
  ],
  "snacks": [
    [
      "lorry1",
      "box1"
    ],
    [
      "lorry2",
      "box1"
    ]
  ]
}
```

The initial transformation was to dump leaves and their paths from the input JSON tree.
See
https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/78#issuecomment-17819519

Comment: Thanks; it looks quite readable too, which I really like. It also helps to know the right terms :) Been playing around a bit with this, to see if I understand whats happening here, not really grasping it, but I hope that will come one day... thanks!

Comment: Nice solution. As the structure is known here, you could simplify the path extraction using `path(.[][][].item)`, which does not need an extra `select` step. The final `map` would also be more readable to me without the `(. | ...)`.

Comment: There's really no reason for `def leaves` here.  For example, you could just write `path(..|scalars)` instead of `path(leaves)`.

Comment: Thanks @peak I will update the answer. This will make it much more concise.

Answer (score 2):

> The answer I'd like to get is lorry1, box1 and lorry2, box1

In this case, you can get it with:

```jq
path(.. | select(.item? == "shoes"))
```

Which returns:

```
["lorry1","box1",0]
["lorry2","box1",0]
```

These are the paths in your object that will lead to an object which `.item` property is set to "shoes"

Comment: brilliant in it's simplicity. I must admit that the path() is a bit of a mystery to me.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generic solution that does not assume the "items" are in arrays, or even that the values associated with the "item" keys are always strings:

```
jq -c '. as $in
  | [paths as $p | select($p[-1] == "item") | $p]
  | group_by(. as $p | $in|getpath($p))
  | .[]
  | (.[0] as $p | $in | getpath($p)) as $v
  | {($v|tostring):  ( map(.[:-1] | if .[-1] | type == "number" then .[:-1] else . end)) }
'
```

### Output

With your input:

```
{"beer":[["lorry1","box2"],["lorry2","box2"]]}
{"potatoes":[["lorry1","box2"]]}
{"shoes":[["lorry1","box1"],["lorry2","box1"]]}
{"snacks":[["lorry1","box1"],["lorry2","box1"]]}
```

If you want the output as a single JSON object, then collect the above into an array and use `add`.

Comment: generic is great; and wow... 3 answers, each with its own benefits. I bow to all of you!

Comment: @Michiel, just to complement an excellent peak's solution, let me also offer you a complete alternative (so that you're aware) - based on utility `jtc` (I'm the creator). with `jtc` the _input invariant_ solution would look like this: `<file.json jtc -w'<item>l:<I>v[-2]' -T'{"{I}":{{$PATH}}}' -lljjm`

Comment: @Dmitry - In the JSON generated by your solution, .potatoes is not an array of arrays.

Comment: @peak, isn't it a bit superfluous - an array of a single array? but, I can envision an argument: it's easier for a subsequent processing, or could be a next step's requirement. In such case the solution could be extended with the option-set to add an array encapsulation to a single array: `<file.json jtc ... / -w'[:]<>f[0][0]<>F' -u'[{{}}];'`